# Calculate remaining character for storing in mysql

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have a column named DESC in mysql database. I set it to Varchar(255) latin-1.

Before storing data in mysql database i use

```
filter_var(mysqli_real_escape_string($value),FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS)
```

My question is how do I implement jquery character counting and maxlength restriction and be able to retrieve & display all the data from the textarea?

My Pseudo code

```
// Set MaxLength to 255

max= 255; 

// Get length of textarea

$(this).val().length

// Count how many &, <,>,",' then multiply by 4 (as each of these characters will convert into &#??? which add extra 4 characters into database)  and Newline (add extra 1 character) in the textarea.

CountSpecial($(this).val()); //bug #1

// calculate remaining characters.

Remaining = max - $(this).val().length -CountSpecial($(this).val());

//Limit the data to varchar(255) to avoid data truncation.

If (Remaining <0) {
//truncate to fix varchar(255)
$(this).val($this.val().substring(0,$this.val().length+Remaining); //bug#2

//recalculate Remaining.
Remaining = max - $(this).val().length -CountSpecial($(this).val());

}
```

Bug #1, I dont know how to accurately calculate the extra characters will be stored into database

Bug #2 I tried

```
$(this).val($this.val().substring(0,$this.val().length-1);
```

but it doesn't behave the way I want, as I use keyup function, if the user keeps holding a key, this calculation will not work.

```
$(this).val($this.val().substring(0,$this.val().length+Remaining);
```

fixed the problem when the user keeps holding a key, but product another problem. If the user key in something like "&" it will remove the last 4 characters from textarea not 1.

Here is my original code 
    http://jsfiddle.net/seth1111/orLh4v4w/5/
How do i fix these bugs?

Thanks.

Comment: how this work ? i mean with `.change()` or `.keydown()`

Comment: aside from the answer: you should not name a column "DESC", because its a reserved mysql keyword and may cause problems with readability. its just not necessary.

Comment: if he use \`DESC\` won't be problem but if he use DESC without ` will be problem

Comment: Thank guys, my problem is data is unpredictably  truncated.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a jQuery Remaining character counter by this simple code.

```
$(function() {  
    $(document).on('keyup paste', '#address', function (e) {       
        var value = $(this).val();
        var limit = 10; // Max character you want to allow
        var length = value.length;  
        var remaining = parseInt(limit - length);
        $('#result').html(remaining+' Character(s) Remaining');
        if(length < limit)
        {           
            $('#result').show();
            $('#error').hide().removeClass('error').html('');
        }
        else if(length > limit)
        {           
            $('#result').hide();
            this.value = this.value.substring(0, limit);
            $('#error').show().addClass('error').html('Maximum ' + limit + ' Characters are allowed!');
        }       
    });
});
```

HTML part is

```
Enter Address: <textarea cols="21" rows="5" name="address" id="address"></textarea>
<p id="result"></p>
<p id="error" style="display: none;"></p>
```

CSS for error class

```
.error {
    color:#f00 !important;
}
```

Just this simple code will done your task.

If you still need help feel free to comment.

Comment: That partly fix my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check special characters and new lines with the String.match function in javascript.

```
realLength = $(this).val().length;
specialCarLength = $(this).val().match(/[&"',<>]/g);
specialCarLength = specialCarLength === null ? 0 : specialCarLength.length * 4;

NewLineCarLength = $(this).val().match(/\n/g);
NewLineCarLength = NewLineCarLength === null ? 0 : NewLineCarLength.length * 2;

NormalCarLength = realLength-specialCarLength/4-NewLineCarLength/2;
```

check my jsFiddle, it demonstrate how you can match special characters and new lines : [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ezevruds/13/)

Comment: Thank you Charkan.
Please check my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/seth1111/orLh4v4w/5/

There is is a problem when using keyup(), I changed it to keydown() as Robert suggested and change

Comment: change it back to 
    $(this).val($(this).val().substring(0,$(this).val().length-1));

I still have problem with the remaining character calculation when a user uses copy/paste.

I tried 
     $(txt).change(function(){
and nothing work.